# SQLite on MFC Out of Memory Error

Tags: sqlite, memory, mfc

Please have a look at the following my codes as I am trying to use SQLite on my MFC application on WM 6.5 and please tell me what I am doing wrong. Any memory leak etc ??

Normally , program works very well. But, there are only two WM device running my application and one of them I havent heard any problem at all. But the other one sometimes gets Out of Memory when I run a select statement. And sometimes , there is no error message but it ruins some of the data. And also I have realised that sometimes it put .dat extention on my Database name.

Any help will be highly appriciated.

```
SelectedID=-1;
iSelectAll=0;
SipShowIM(SIPF_OFF);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
CString FindStr1,FindStr2;
m_Edit1.GetWindowText(FindStr1); FindStr1.TrimLeft(); FindStr1.TrimRight();
m_Edit2.GetWindowText(FindStr2); FindStr2.TrimLeft(); FindStr2.TrimRight();
if(FindStr1 == L"" && FindStr2 == L"")
{
    MessageBox(L"Please enter a keyword to search!",L"Product Search",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR); return -1;   
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
bIgnore = TRUE;
int Ret     = 0;
sqlite3 *db; sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;

m_lv1.DeleteAllItems();
const char *data = NULL;
if( !sqlite3_open(chDatabaseName, &db) )
{
    CString Str;
    CString SearchField = L"";
           SearchField.Format(L" WHERE Description1 LIKE '%%%s%%' AND Description1 LIKE '%%%s%%' ",(LPCTSTR)FindStr1,(LPCTSTR)FindStr2);

    Str.Format(L"SELECT Status,Description1,ProductID,Stock,Code,UnitRate1,Size,Unit1,Unit2,DefaultUnit,VAT,Notes  FROM Products %s ORDER BY Status DESC, GroupID DESC, Description1 DESC",(LPCTSTR)SearchField);

    char chSqlString[1024+1];
    memset(chSqlString,0x00,sizeof(chSqlString)-1);wcstombs(chSqlString,Str,1024);chSqlString[Str.GetLength()]='\0';
    if ( sqlite3_prepare_v2( db, chSqlString, -1, &stmt, NULL )== SQLITE_OK)
    {
       m_lv1.SendMessage(WM_SETREDRAW,0,0);
       while( sqlite3_step( stmt ) == SQLITE_ROW ) 
       {
           CString StrDescription,StrSize; 
           data = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text( stmt, 0 ); m_lv1.InsertItem( 0 , L"",atol(data)-1);
                                                                m_lv1.SetItemText(0, 1,L"1");
            data = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text( stmt, 1 ); if(data) StrDescription=CString(data); else StrDescription=L"";             
            data = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text( stmt, 2 ); if(data) m_lv1.SetItemText(0, 3,CString(data)); else  m_lv1.SetItemText(0, 3,L"");
            data = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text( stmt, 3 ); if(data) m_lv1.SetItemText(0, 4,CString(data)); else  m_lv1.SetItemText(0, 4,L"");
            data = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text( stmt, 4 ); if(data) m_lv1.SetItemText(0, 5,CString(data)); else  m_lv1.SetItemText(0, 5,L"");
            data = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text( stmt, 5 ); if(data) m_lv1.SetItemText(0, 6,CString(data)); else  m_lv1.SetItemText(0, 6,L"");

            data = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text( stmt, 6 ); if(data) StrSize=CString(data); else StrSize=L"";               

            //data = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text( stmt, 6 ); if(data) m_lv1.SetItemText(0, 7,CString(data)); else  m_lv1.SetItemText(0, 7,L"");
            data = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text( stmt, 7 ); if(data) m_lv1.SetItemText(0, 8,CString(data)); else  m_lv1.SetItemText(0, 8,L"");
            data = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text( stmt, 8 ); if(data) m_lv1.SetItemText(0, 9,CString(data)); else  m_lv1.SetItemText(0, 9,L"");
            data = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text( stmt, 9 ); if(data) m_lv1.SetItemText(0,10,CString(data)); else  m_lv1.SetItemText(0,10,L"");
            data = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text( stmt,10 ); if(data) m_lv1.SetItemText(0,11,CString(data)); else  m_lv1.SetItemText(0,11,L"");
            data = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text( stmt,11 ); if(data) m_lv1.SetItemText(0,12,CString(data)); else  m_lv1.SetItemText(0,12,L"");

            StrDescription = StrDescription.Trim()+L" "+StrSize.Trim();
            m_lv1.SetItemText(0, 2,StrDescription);
            m_lv1.SetItemText(0, 7,StrSize);
       }    
       m_lv1.SendMessage(WM_SETREDRAW,1,0);
   }
   else
   {
         MessageBox(CString(sqlite3_errmsg(db)),L"SELECT Err",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR); Ret = -1;// Out of memory error happens here !
   }
}
else
{      
    MessageBox(CString(sqlite3_errmsg(db)),L"Open DB",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);  Ret =-1;
}
sqlite3_finalize( stmt ); 
sqlite3_close(db); 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
return Ret;
```

And some codes on for update or Insert Statement

```
COleDateTime today(COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime());
EndTime.Format(L"%02d:%02d:%02d",today.GetHour(),today.GetMinute(),today.GetSecond());

CString Str,SQLStr,SQLStrA,StrTableName;

pTab1->m_Edit6.GetWindowText(Str); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight();
if(Str==L"" && SaleType!=3 && SaleType!=33 && dbR31!=0 )
{
    MessageBox(_T("Please select a payment method!"), _T("Missing Detail"), MB_OK|MB_ICONWARNING); return -1;
}
SQLStrA=L"";
switch(SaleType)
{
    case  1: SQLStrA.Format(L"UPDATE Config SET OrderSN=%ld"  ,(SaleID+1)); StrTableName=L"Orders"   ; break;
    case  2: SQLStrA.Format(L"UPDATE Config SET InvoiceSN=%ld",(SaleID+1)); StrTableName=L"Invoices" ; break;
    case  3: SQLStrA.Format(L"UPDATE Config SET ReturnSN=%ld" ,(SaleID+1)); StrTableName=L"Returns"  ; break;
    case 11: SQLStrA=L""; StrTableName=L"Orders"   ; break;
    case 22: SQLStrA=L""; StrTableName=L"Invoices" ; break;
    case 33: SQLStrA=L""; StrTableName=L"Returns"  ; break;
}

if(SaleType==1 ||SaleType==2 || SaleType==3) 
{
   SQLStr=L"INSERT INTO "+StrTableName+L" (OrderID,CustomerID,OrderNo,OrderDate,DeliveryDate,Payment,Comments1,Comments2,Comments3,DscTotal,VATTotal,NetTotal,Status,StartTime,EndTime) VALUES (";      
   Str.Format(_T("%ld"),SaleID);                                              SQLStr = SQLStr +L" " +Str+ L" ,";
   Str.Format(_T("%ld"),SCID);                                                SQLStr = SQLStr +L" " +Str+ L" ,";
   pTab1->m_Edit1.GetWindowText(Str)       ; Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L" '"+Str+ L"',";
   pTab1->m_DateTime1.GetWindowText(Str)   ; Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L" '"+Str+ L"',";
   pTab1->m_DateTime2.GetWindowText(Str)   ; Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L" '"+Str+ L"',";
   pTab1->m_Edit6.GetWindowText(Str)       ; Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L" '"+Str+ L"',";
   pTab1->m_Comments1.GetWindowText(Str)   ; Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L" '"+Str+ L"',";
   pTab1->m_Comments2.GetWindowText(Str)   ; Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L" '"+Str+ L"',";
   pTab1->m_Comments3.GetWindowText(Str)   ; Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L" '"+Str+ L"',";
   pTab2->m_DscTotal.GetWindowText(Str)    ; Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"  "+Str+ L" ,";
   pTab2->m_VATTotal.GetWindowText(Str)    ; Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"  "+Str+ L" ,";
   pTab2->m_NetTotal.GetWindowText(Str)    ; Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"  "+Str+ L" , 0 ,";
                                                                              SQLStr = SQLStr +L" '"+StartTime+L"',";
                                                                              SQLStr = SQLStr +L" '"+EndTime+ L"' )";
}
if(SaleType==11 || SaleType==22 || SaleType==33) 
{
   SQLStrA=L"";
   SQLStr=L"UPDATE "+StrTableName+L" SET ";       
   pTab1->m_DateTime1.GetWindowText(Str)   ; Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"    [OrderDate]='"+Str+ L"',";
   pTab1->m_DateTime2.GetWindowText(Str)   ; Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L" [DeliveryDate]='"+Str+ L"',";
   pTab1->m_Edit6.GetWindowText(Str)       ; Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"      [Payment]='"+Str+ L"',";
   pTab1->m_Comments1.GetWindowText(Str)   ; Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"    [Comments1]='"+Str+ L"',";
   pTab1->m_Comments2.GetWindowText(Str)   ; Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"    [Comments2]='"+Str+ L"',";
   pTab1->m_Comments3.GetWindowText(Str)   ; Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"    [Comments3]='"+Str+ L"',";
   pTab2->m_DscTotal.GetWindowText(Str)    ; Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"     [DscTotal]='"+Str+ L"',";
   pTab2->m_VATTotal.GetWindowText(Str)    ; Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"     [VATTotal]='"+Str+ L"',";
   pTab2->m_NetTotal.GetWindowText(Str)    ; Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"     [NetTotal]='"+Str+ L"',";
                                                                              SQLStr = SQLStr +L"     [Status]=0,";
                                                                              SQLStr = SQLStr +L"      [EndTime]='"+EndTime+ L"' ";
                                 Str.Format(_T("%ld"),SCID);                  SQLStr = SQLStr +L" WHERE [CustomerID]=" +Str+ L" AND ";
                                 Str.Format(_T("%ld"),SaleID);                SQLStr = SQLStr +L"          [OrderID]=" +Str+ L" ";

}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int Ret     = 0;
sqlite3 *db; sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;
if(SQLStrA != L"")
{
    if( !sqlite3_open(chDatabaseName, &db) )
    {
        char chSqlString[1024+1];
        memset(chSqlString,0x00,sizeof(chSqlString)-1);wcstombs(chSqlString,SQLStrA,1024);chSqlString[SQLStrA.GetLength()]='\0';
        if ( sqlite3_prepare_v2( db, chSqlString, -1, &stmt, NULL )== SQLITE_OK)
        {
            int UpdateRet = sqlite3_step( stmt );
            if (( UpdateRet!= SQLITE_DONE )&&( UpdateRet!= SQLITE_ROW ))
            {
                MessageBox(CString(sqlite3_errmsg(db)),L"[SerialNo]",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR); Ret = -1;                   
            }
       }
       else
       {
             MessageBox(CString(sqlite3_errmsg(db)),L"[SerialNo]",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR); Ret = -1;
       }
    }
    else
    {      
        MessageBox(CString(sqlite3_errmsg(db)),L"Open DB",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);  Ret =-1;
    }
    sqlite3_finalize( stmt ); sqlite3_close(db); 
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if(Ret!=-1)
{
    if( !sqlite3_open(chDatabaseName, &db) )
    {
        char chSqlString[2048+1];
        memset(chSqlString,0x00,sizeof(chSqlString)-1);wcstombs(chSqlString,SQLStr,2048);chSqlString[SQLStr.GetLength()]='\0';
        if ( sqlite3_prepare_v2( db, chSqlString, -1, &stmt, NULL )== SQLITE_OK)
        {
            int UpdateRet = sqlite3_step( stmt );
            if (( UpdateRet!= SQLITE_DONE )&&( UpdateRet!= SQLITE_ROW ))
            {
                MessageBox(CString(sqlite3_errmsg(db)),L"[Master]",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR); Ret = -1;                   
            }
       }
       else
       {
             MessageBox(CString(sqlite3_errmsg(db)),L"[Master]",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR); Ret = -1;
       }
    }
    else
    {      
        MessageBox(CString(sqlite3_errmsg(db)),L"Open DB",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);  Ret =-1;
    }
    sqlite3_finalize( stmt ); sqlite3_close(db);
}
return Ret;
```

And another update or Insert statements which I am using.

```
CString Str,SQLStr,StrTableName;
if(SaleType==1 || SaleType==11) StrTableName=L"OrderDetails"  ; 
if(SaleType==2 || SaleType==22) StrTableName=L"InvoiceDetails"; 
if(SaleType==3 || SaleType==33) StrTableName=L"ReturnDetails" ; 

int Ret     = 0;
sqlite3 *db; sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;   
    if( !sqlite3_open(chDatabaseName, &db) )
    {
   char chSqlString[2048+1];
   for( int i=0 ; i < pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemCount() ; i++)
   {
     if(_wtol(pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i,9)) < 0) //if RecordID == -1
     {
         if(pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i,0).Trim()!=L"*")
         {
               SQLStr=L"INSERT INTO "+StrTableName+L" (OrderID,CustomerID,Qty,Unit,Price,Vat,Dsc,Notes,ProductID,DetailID,Reason ) VALUES (";               
               Str.Format(_T("%ld"),SaleID)    ;                                      SQLStr = SQLStr +L"  " +Str+ L" ,";
               Str.Format(_T("%ld"),SCID);                                            SQLStr = SQLStr +L"  " +Str+ L" ,";
               Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i, 1); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"  " +Str+ L" ,";//Qty
               Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i, 3); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L" '" +Str+ L"',";//Unit
               Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i, 4); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"  " +Str+ L" ,";//Price
               Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i, 5); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"  " +Str+ L" ,";//VAT Rate
               Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i, 6); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"  " +Str+ L" ,";//DSC Rate
               Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i, 7); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L" '" +Str+ L"',";//Notes
               Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i, 8); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"  " +Str+ L" ,";//ProductID
             //Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i, 9); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"  " +Str+ L" ,";//RecordID - OrderID
               Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i,10); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"  " +Str+ L" ,";//DetailID
             //Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i,11); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"  " +Str+ L" ,";//PromotionID
               Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i,12); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L" '" +Str+ L"')";//Reason
         }           
     }
     else
     {
         if(pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i,0).Trim()!=L"*")
         {
               SQLStr=L"UPDATE "+StrTableName+L" SET ";
               Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i, 1); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"   Qty= " +Str+ L" ,";//Qty
               Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i, 3); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"  Unit='" +Str+ L"',";//Unit
               Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i, 4); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L" Price= " +Str+ L" ,";//Price
               Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i, 5); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"   Vat= " +Str+ L" ,";//VAT Rate
               Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i, 6); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"   Dsc= " +Str+ L" ,";//DSC Rate
               Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i, 7); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L" Notes='" +Str+ L"',";//Notes
               Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i,12); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"Reason='" +Str+ L"' ";//Notes
               Str.Format(_T("%ld"),SaleID);                                          SQLStr = SQLStr +L" WHERE OrderID=" +Str+ L" AND ";   
               Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i,10); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"      DetailID=" +Str+ L" ";
         }
         else
         {
               SQLStr=L"DELETE FROM "+StrTableName+L" ";
               Str.Format(_T("%ld"),SaleID);                                          SQLStr = SQLStr +L" WHERE OrderID=" +Str+ L" AND ";   
               Str = pTab2->m_lv2.GetItemText(i,10); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight(); SQLStr = SQLStr +L"      DetailID=" +Str+ L" ";
         }
    }

    memset(chSqlString,0x00,sizeof(chSqlString)-1);wcstombs(chSqlString,SQLStr,2048);chSqlString[SQLStr.GetLength()]='\0';
    if ( sqlite3_prepare_v2( db, chSqlString, -1, &stmt, NULL )== SQLITE_OK)
    {
        int UpdateRet = sqlite3_step( stmt );
        if (( UpdateRet!= SQLITE_DONE )&&( UpdateRet!= SQLITE_ROW ))
        {
                MessageBox(CString(sqlite3_errmsg(db)),L"[Detail]",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR); Ret = -1;                   
        }
     }
     else
     {
        MessageBox(CString(sqlite3_errmsg(db)),L"[Detail]",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR); Ret = -1;
     }
   }
   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
else
{      
   MessageBox(CString(sqlite3_errmsg(db)),L"Open DB",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);  Ret =-1;
}

sqlite3_finalize( stmt ); sqlite3_close( db );
return 0;
```

Comment: are you sure that the select statement prepared in your first function (including the search criteria) will not run over 1024 characters? As your wcstombs(chSqlString,Str,1024); maybe safe, chSqlString[Str.GetLength()]='\0' can write beyond the predefined buffer of 1024 chars. Please check

Comment: Yes I am sure that it is not exceeding the limit as 1024 is more than enough for the select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am really sorry to everybody as I found the problem is not with SQLite , the problem is with  listview and it is completely sorted now.

Thanks again